# Not able to get the details of the page through url and display it to index page codeigniter - Jquery

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

This is the code

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click','.show_more',function(){
    var ID = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.read_more').hide();
    $('.loding').show();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'ajax_page.php',
        data:'id='+ID,
        success:function(html){
            //alert(url);
            $('#read_more_main'+ID).remove();
            $('.listdiv').append(html); // in the index page
        }
      });

     });
   });
  </script>
```

I am Using Codeigniter and Jquery .I wants to get the details of ajax_page.php and display it to .listdiv in the index page. I am not able to access the ajax_page.php but it displays the entire index page inside the  listdiv. Please tell me what I have done wrong here. And how I call ajax_page.php correctly.

Comment: make it a function then call it

Answer (score 0):

Prevent the click event

```
$(document).on('click','.show_more',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
```